# Have 8 different large images and and would like to map the corresponding location to many polygons none of which overlap

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 8 large image files that are all the same size.  Lets just say 5000 by 5000 pixels.  I am generating many polygons (basically a map) that will fill up a area of 5000 by 5000. None of these polygons will overlap.

I am inheriting from the Polygon class and the code looks something like:

```
public enum eMap
{
    Map1,
    Map2,
    Map3,
    Map4,
    Map5,
    Map6,
    Map7,
    Map8,
}

public class mPolygon : Polygon
{
    public eMap CurrentMap
    {
        get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(CurrentMapProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CurrentMapProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentMapProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register(
         "State", typeof(MapEnum), typeof(mPolygon), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static ImageBrush Map2 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map2.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map3 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map3.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map4 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map4.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map1 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map5 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map5.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map6 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map6.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map7 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map7.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map8 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map8.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

    public static ImageBrush Map1 = new BitmapImage(
       new Uri("G:\\code\\Maps\\map1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)));

}
```

How can I fill up the corresponding background (Fill) of the Polygon from the image that it is pointing too.

So in other words if I have a polygon with the points (x,y) = (12,25), (45,59), (98,65), (101, 70) and that Polygon's CurrentMap == eMap.Map4 then I want to take the same polygon shape from the 4th image file and display it in my polygon.  I need to do this with all the polygons and if the CurrentMap changes for a polygon to a different image then I need to show that change as well.

Just another way to explain it:

I lay the map images done one layer upon each other (they are all the same size).  So I have 8 map layers on top of each other.  Then I lay a layer of polygons on top of all those images.  The polygons are placed so that they don't overlap with each other but they do cover the entire space the maps take up.  So a particular polygon might be on x1,y1 (and be some odd shape) and it would use map5 it would show a piece of map5 that is the same size and place of this polygon.  The polygon next to the one I just mentioned could be using map2 and it would only show the area of map2 that it is inside of itself.  I hope that explains it a bit better.

Comment: I'm a little confused -- which version of `Polygon` are you using? It seems as though [these versions of `Polygon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are sealed.

Comment: Yeah my bad.  It is sealed.  I will need to do a work around for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should register for value changes of `State` and change the background accordingly:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentMapProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.Register(
     "State", typeof(eMap), typeof(mPolygon), new PropertyMetadata((eMap)(-1), OnStateChanged));

private static readonly IDictionary<eMap, ImageBrush> mapping = new Dictionary<eMap, ImageBrush>
{
    { eMap.Map1, Map1 },
    { eMap.Map2, Map2 },
    { eMap.Map3, Map3 }
};

private static void OnStateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    mPolygon polygon = (mPolygon)d;

    polygon.Fill = mapping[e.NewValue];
}
```

Comment: Yeah I like that better but it still doesn't quite do what I need it to do.  I added more to my original question that will hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Ok so you may continue this way and set the `Clip` property of the images to only include the part of the image that is "inside" the polygon. I don't know if WPF will handle this in an appropriate manner if you have many polygons in terms of performance but it's worth a try. Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `false` (in PropertyMetadata) is not a valid default value for type `eMap`. Change it to either `eMap.Map1` or `default(eMap)`. And also fix the dictionary keys, as they are all `eMap.Map1`.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the catch: `false` is just a copy/paste from original question, keys are my own copy-pasting and to avoid any silent error I've set the default values to -1. (it's why it's always good to have a special 0 value in enum) :)

Comment: `(eMap)-1` is also not a valid value. Just use `default(eMap)` instead, as there must be a valid default value.

Comment: @Clemens Hum indeed in the dependency properties plumbing may have some side effects, curious about which ones... But never a good idea to have as default value a valid value that could be missed by the user of the code base.

Comment: "But never a good idea to have as default value a valid value". Wrong, the opposite is true. If you set the default value of a dependency property by property metadata, it must always be a valid value. Otherwise you'll get an exception in DependencyProperty.Register.

Comment: @Clemens Yes for dependency properties I agree, it's why I was mentioning the side effects in this case. Believe me you don't want to track this kind of bug ;) With reference and nullable types `null` is the perfect safe-guard: it blows up when the value was omitted. But with value types and particularly enums if the default value `0` is valid then you can't tell the difference between "the user did not provided any value" and "the user provided the default value". It's one of the reasons why nullables were introduced. So I often use an absurd value like `_ = 0`.